# Status bar not covering the Navigation Drawer

Tags: android, android-layout, navigation-drawer

I have ImageView in Navigation Drawer, and I wan't status bar to overlay it. I have tried some instruction from internet and stackoverflow including "fitsSystemWindos=true", add translucent flag, but nothing works. Can somebody help? (BTW, min api 21, testing on Marshmallow)

Also I have problem with scrolling, it just doesn't work

**v21/styles.xml**

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**First part of activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!--Drawer Layout-->
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:overScrollMode="always"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <!-- Header -->
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:src="@drawable/example"
            android:id="@+id/drawer_header"
            android:onClick="selfEdit"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

**And some lines from MainActivity.java**

```
Window window = getWindow();            
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
window.setStatusBarColor(0x80000000);
```

[image]

Comment: dude what kind of drawable do you have in your app? @Dima

Comment: @ankitagrawal ImageView from PNG. Sorry, forget to add screenshot

Comment: Can you please add screenshot ?

Comment: try adding   <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>

Comment: @TusharSheth App is now fullscreen, status bar hidden, and when I make him visible - it's black

Comment: set <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#FFFFFFFF</item>. So status bar color will be white. If that is what you are asking for.

Comment: No, I'm want status bar to overlay my image view. On the screenshot - what I have. My status bar color now set to #80000000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I decided to decline ImageView and just put my image as background (with white space below it) Maybe my code will help someone (but hey, better find more usable solution)

```
public static void setDrawerBackground(MainActivity activity, Bitmap 
        if (bitmap==null)
            return;
        Point p = new Point();
        activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(p);
        Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(activity.findViewById(R.id.drawer).getWidth(), p.y, bitmap.getConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(b);
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        Matrix m = new Matrix();
        float scale = b.getWidth()/bitmap.getWidth();
        m.setScale(scale, scale);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, m, null);
        activity.findViewById(R.id.drawer).setBackground(new BitmapDrawable(b));
    }
```